# How to deploy to Azure a Blazor ASP.NET CORE HOSTED vS2019 template project?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have figured out how to deploy the SERVER SIDE and CLIENT SIDE template but not this one.

I have tried to publish the BLAZORCORE.SERVER as SELF CONTAINED to an App Service but get the error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Assets file 'C:\Users\punko\source\repos\BlazorCore\BlazorCore.Client\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netstandard2.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. BlazorCore.Server       0

Comment: What project/template exactly?  Is BLAZORCORE.SERVER part of the Hosted template?

Comment: If you add the Blazor template add on to VS2019 is called Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted)